# Power BI reusign datasets

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have one dashboards one with all data from all countries, and I would like one single dashboard for each country reusing the previous dataset. I would like to do that to minimize the space needed in cloud for those dashboards. Also there is users that only should have access to data to each own country. 
I tried to create a parameter to filter by country but it is not allowed when I reuse a data set as data source.

Could you please help me to find a way to reuse dataset filtering by country in order to minimize the resources needed?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Either use [Row-level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-rls) to define which rows should be visible to the current user, or make separate reports for each country and share the data source between them. If you use Direct Query, there will be single copy of the data. Or you can publish one report with data for all countries to the cloud, and [use it as a data source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-report-lifecycle-datasets) for the per-country reports.